# werkzeug gets empty stream

Tags: python-2.7, werkzeug

> input content type was
>   multipart/form-data.  In this situation the stream will be empty and form will
>   contain the regular POST / PUT data, files will contain the uploaded files as FileStorage objects.
>
> input content
>   type was application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  Then the stream will be empty and form will
>   contain the regular POST / PUT data and files will be empty.
>
> the input
>   content type was neither of them, stream points to a LimitedStream with the input data for further
>   processing.

According to the doc of werkzeug, I set the content-type in header as "text/plain",
but the stream is still empty. my Code is as below:

```
def hello_world(environ, start_response):
    CHUNKSIZE = 65563
    request = Request(environ)
    print environ["wsgi.input"].readline()
    print request.base_url
    print request.data[:100]
    print len(request.data)
    print request.headers
    print request.form
    print request.stream.readline()
```